# Javascript autocomplete for multiple textboxes

Tags: javascript, php

I found this code online and did some editing to make it pull data from my database rather that from the file itself.

Anyhow, I'm not an expert by any means with Javascript and I would like to have two text boxes. The second one will be uneditable and will be autofilled once the model is selected. At the moment the database table only has two fields and I would like to have the second text box autofilled with that second column, ID.

Can anyone help me out with this. It would be greatly appreciated.

```
        <!doctype html>
         <?php

         include('mysql_connect.php');

        $arr    = array();
        $sql    = "select model from models";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());  
        while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
         $test = implode($row, ',');
         $arr[] = '"'.$test.'"';
        }

        echo '<pre>';
        $test = implode($arr, ',');
        echo $test;
        echo '</pre>';
         ?>

        <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8" />
          <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
          <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
          <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
          <script>
          $(function() {
            var availableTags = [
                <?php echo $test; ?>
            ];
            $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
              source: availableTags
            });
          });
          </script>
        </head>
        <body>

        <div class="ui-widget">
          <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
          <input type="text" id="tags" />
        </div>


        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: why are you mixing html and php in the same file and why do you use the deprecated mysql_* functions?

Comment: Like I said above. I found the code online and as for the mixed of php and HTML I don't get what the issue is... I'm testing this out so I can get what I need then I will move the PHP to its own file and include it in the file.

Lastly, I have no idea what your talking about with the "deprecated mysql_* functions".

I need help with this. Not a stern talking to.

Comment: Here's some information about why those functions are a bad idea: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: I appreciate the effort but this is not a problem for me at the moment. If you can help me with the my original question that would be great.